# pasar parámetro como propiedad de un objeto

Tags: javascript, array

He buscado como el parámetro de una función y asignarlo como propiedad de un objeto, intente con backticks pero no esta bien la sintaxis, no se que método sirva para eso... este es el código:

```
function arreglodeObjetos(num,str) {
let arr = [];
for (let i = 0; i <= num; i++)
    arr.push({str: i})
console.log(arr)
return arr
}
```

---

```
arreglodeObjetos(5,'hola') // deberia retornar: [{"hola":1},{"hola":2},{"hola":3},{"hola":4},{"hola":5}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En este caso tienes que poner str entre corchetes, de esa forma puedes hacer que el nombre de la propiedad tome el valor de `str`; digamos que es la forma para crear la `key` tal que así:

```
 let key = 'key';
 let obj = {
  [key]: "the_value",
};

 function arreglodeObjetos(num,str) {
let arr = [];
for (let i = 0; i <= num; i++)
    arr.push({[str]: i})
console.log(arr)
return arr
}
arreglodeObjetos(5,"hola")
```

Comment: oh gracias por la ayuda¡